# How to convert different dates with string format to specific format like YYYYMMDD

Tags: c#, date-formatting, c#-5.0, c#-8.0

I am trying to convert different string date formats to a specific format i.e., YYYYMMDD and all the incoming dates are valid. How can I return a new list of strings representing this format

Comment: for dates there's DateTime type in C#. and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-5.0) you can find how to convert it to string with formatting

Comment: A date 3/4/2000 could be a third of April or a fourth of March. Without additional hints it is impossible to know for sure which is it.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to a list of strings? A better choice would be to parse the input list into a list of DateTime instances. Types exist for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.Parse() to get the date/time information into a standard DateTime object and then you can output it any way that you like.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<string> TransformDateFormat(List<string> dates)
{
    var formats = new string[]
    {
        "yyyy/MM/dd",
        "dd/MM/yyyy",
        "MM-dd-yyyy",
        "yyyyMMdd"
    };

    return dates
        .Select(date => DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, null).ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
        .ToList();
}
```

You must specify all possible formats.